# curl to compile a list of redirected pages

Tags: bash, curl

Suppose I have a bash script that goes through a file that contains a list of old URLs that have all been redirected.

`curl --location http://destination.com` will process a page by following a redirect. However, I'm interested not in the content, but on where the redirect points so that I can update my records.

What is the command-line option for curl to output what that new location for the URL is?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You wou want to leave out the `--location/-L` flag, and use `-w`, checking the `redirect_url` variable.  `curl -w "%{redirect_url}" http://someurl.com` should do it.

Used in a script:

```
REDIRECT=`curl -w "%{redirect_url}" http://someurl.com`
echo "http://someurl.com redirects to: ${REDIRECT}"
```

---

From the [curl man page](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html):

> ```
> -w, --write-out <format>
> ```
>
> Make curl display information on stdout after a completed transfer. The 
>   format is a string that may contain plain text mixed with any number
>   of variables. The format can be specified as a literal "string", or
>   you can have curl read the format from a file with "@filename" and to
>   tell curl to read the format from stdin you write "@-".
>
> The variables present in the output format will be substituted by the
>   value or text that curl thinks fit, as described below. All variables
>   are specified as %{variable_name} and to output a normal % you just
>   write them as %%. You can output a newline by using \n, a carriage
>   return with \r and a tab space with \t.
>
> **NOTE:** The %-symbol is a special symbol in the win32-environment, where
>   all occurrences of % must be doubled when using this option.
>
> The variables available are:
>
> ...
>   `redirect_url` When an HTTP request was made without -L to follow 
>   redirects, this variable will show the actual URL a redirect *would*
>   take you to. (Added in 7.18.2)
>   ...

Answer (score 2):

This might work (as a starting point)

```
curl -sI google.com | head -1 | grep 301 | wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

```
man curl
```

then

```
search redirect_url
```

> **redirect_url**   When  a HTTP request was made without -L to follow
>   redirects, this variable will show the actual URL a redirect would
>   take you to. (Added
>                                in 7.18.2)

the variable above is for `-w/--write-out <format>`